# Can I cut into concrete floor in kitchen?

Tags: concrete

I need to run a gas line for a new stove. No room in the attic so need a 3x3 inch, estimated 12 foot trench in kitchen concrete floor. Wondering if anyone can offer advice.  I'm just concerned about cutting into the floor. Any concerns or issues I should be aware of and is this normal practice?  My gas guy suggested this as no other way to get gas line to new stove location. Thanks.

Comment: depending on the type of dirt under the house, you may be able to tunnel under the floor and then drill down through the floor into the tunnel

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you can cut a trench through your concrete floor.

Be sure that you locate any existing wires or pipes that are in the path of the cut. A concrete saw with water will keep the dust to a minimum. Using a wet/dry vac to immediately suck up the water/dust will also help.  Be sure to seal off the space as best you can with plastic sheeting to keep the concrete dust out of the rest of the house.

You will likely want to dig below the concrete to make a space for the new pipe and then back fill to the level of the bottom of the concrete with sand or pea gravel.  Finally fill the cut with concrete and trowel it level with the uncut part.

Is it a lot of work?  Sure, but there is often no other way.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your response. Understand the mess but she wants her gas stove so a must do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a second answer for visibility, but depending on what part of the country you are in, you may have a "post-tensioned slab" foundation.  This type of foundation has tension cables strung through it at regular intervals that provide a force to hold the foundation together and add strength.

If you just start cutting into a post-tensioned slab, it's likely you will cut or damage some of the cables.  To work properly with one of these foundations, you have to know where the cable are and work around them.  The full details are beyond the scope of this question, but you need to do your research and figure out if this is the type of slab you have before starting or even seriously planning this type of work.

Comment: I live in North Florida. Don't plan to cut through entire floor, only about 3 x 3 deep. Enough to add PVC pipe for gas line.  Thoughts, advise?  Thank you.

Comment: 3" deep is enough to hit a cable if that's the type of foundation you have.  Unfortunately, I'm not that much of an expert on running gas lines, I just knew that tension cables can be an issue and wanted to let you know.